# Symfony unit testing

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

Following is my directory structure:

```
     |-vendor
     |---bin
     |---phpunit
     |---autoload.php
     |---psr
     |---sebastian
     |---phar-io
     |---composer
     |---symfony
     |-.htaccess
     |-composer.lock
     |-includes
     |---application_top.php
     |-routes
     |---routes.php
     |-modules
     |---Controllers
     |----CheckoutGatewayController.php
     |-tests
     |---Controllers
     |----tests_common_includes.php
     |-composer.phar
```

I am trying to run `./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit --bootstrap tests/tests_common_includes.php tests/Controllers/CheckoutGatewayTests.php` from my base directory but it gives me error `Class 'tests/Controllers/CheckoutGatewayTests' could not be found in 'tests/Controllers/CheckoutGatewayTests.php'.`

If I try `./vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap tests/tests_common_includes.php tests/Controllers/CheckoutGatewayTests.php` then I get the error `Unable to guess the Kernel directory`. I tried to look up symfony's documentation : it suggests using either `-c app` option or changing `phpunit.dist.xml` file. But I have neither of those in my directory. There is no xml file and no app folder.

How can I execute my tests? My test file `CheckoutGatewayTests.php` looks like this :

```
     <?php

     use \Controllers\CheckoutGatewayController;
     use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

     class CheckoutGatewayTests extends WebTestCase {


     public function testChargebackCallback() {
             $client = static::createClient();
             $client->request('GET', '/post/hello-world');
         }

     }
```

Edit: my composer.json file

```
        {
        "require": {
            "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
            "psr/log": "^1.0",
            "zircote/swagger-php": "^2.0",
            "sentry/sentry": "^1.8",
            "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.52",
            "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
            "symfony/routing": "^3.4",
            "symfony/http-kernel": "^3.4",
            "symfony/dependency-injection": "^3.4",
            "symfony/framework-bundle": "^3.4",
            "prbdias/mbway-php": "0.1"
        },

        "require-dev": {
            "phpunit/phpunit": "^6"
        },

        "config": {
            "optimize-autoloader": true
        },

        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "": ["modules/", "tests/","routes/"]
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: it looks like you forgot the `namespace` declaration in your test-file. Make sure it's correct according to a `"require"` (or `"require-dev"`) statement in your `composer.json`
Also, if you're using **custom bootstrap** for your unit tests, make sure you included `vendor/autoload.php` in `tests/tests_common_includes.php`

Comment: I added my composer.json file in question. As per it's require-dev I added "namespace phpunit\phpunit" in my test file. Still the same error. Also, I am already including vendor/autoload.php

Comment: if you added the namespace just after the comment, you might need to dump the auto-loader again. it must not be with your project, it's just a general comment I do here, so your mileage may vary and this might not be related to your issue.